# angular 5 unit tests fail when rxjs switchmap used

Tags: angular, redux, jasmine, angular5, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a component where an action is dispatched on store and then some data  is returned from inside this switchmap

this issue is with unit testing this component. if I remove switchmap the code runs fine otherwise it fails with

```
undefined is not a constructor
```

here is my spec file

```
    it('should dispatch xyz action oninit', async(() => {
    mockStore.select.and.returnValue(MockService.xyz);

    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(mockStore.select).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockStore.select).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fromStore.xyz);
    expect(component.data$).toEqual(Observable.of(MockService.xyz));
}));
```

here is component oninit method

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data$ = this.store.select(fromStore.xyz)
        .switchMap((val) => { return Observable.of{zyz};}
}
```

if i remove this switchmap test runs fine  the error i see here is

```
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.store.select(fromStore.zyz)
                .switchMap')
```

I am using phantomjs and jasmine to run my specs

Comment: "return Observable.of   {   zyz  }", you mean "return Observable.of( zyz )" with zyz an already existing object ?

Comment: what is `this.store`? Is it a service? Have you mocked the service?

Comment: yes it is the redux store service i am mocking and yes it is returning observable.of({zyz}) this was just to post for question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to not importing map operator in my component.ts file. While unit testing this operator could not be resolved

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```